# Why does a leading slash cause relative URLs in links on my site to resolve to the wrong page?

Tags: html, url

On my page http://example.com/games/games/ipad.html I have links such as:

```
<a href="/../2010/junee2010/44/Grand Theft Auto Chinatown Wars HD.html">
```

This should resolve to the URL

```
http://example.com/games/2010/junee2010/44/Grand%20Theft%20Auto%20Chinatown%20Wars%20HD.html
```

but the "/games" is missing from the URL path when the link is followed. Instead, the link resolves to:

```
http://example.com/2010/junee2010/44/Grand%20Theft%20Auto%20Chinatown%20Wars%20HD.html
```

I try moving the page with the links to http://sitename/games/games/games/ipad.html, but it didn't change the URLs of the links. Using jQuery to remove the leading "/" from the href fixes the link URLs, but this is a overly complex solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the slash at the beginning:

```
<a href="../2010/junee2010/44/Grand Theft Auto Chinatown Wars HD.html">link</a>
```

Comment: This is parse of site - there are many places where I must manual do this - can I do this with page url manipulation?

Comment: No. The slash at the beginning makes the whole URL relative to the root of the site (`http://sitename/`).