# jQuery Autocomplete, problems calling function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am running jQuery autocomplete on a screen that calls the function to get the data from another .aspx page. The setup works fine when running locally but when I host it I get an error has occurred which is the message I setup for when it doesn't work. The only issue is that I can't figure out why it would work locally but not when hosted (which is on localhost by the way).

ASPX page with the autocomplete box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('<%=txtCustomerType.ClientID %>').onclick = SearchText();
});

    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/../JQueryAutoComplete.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'Customer':'" + document.getElementById(
                        '<%=txtCustomerType.ClientID %>').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('An error occurred!');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        select: function (a, b) {
            checkDirty = false;
            $(this).val(b.item.value);
            $("form").submit()
        }
    });
```

Code behind of the the Jquery page that it calls:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
    [WebMethod]


    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string Customer) {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString());

        using (SqlConnection con = dbConnection) {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "PL_CustomerTypes_IntelliSearch", dbConnection)) {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchText", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Customer;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                da.Fill(ds);

                DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
                dtResults = ds.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow R in dtResults.Rows) {
                    string strResult = (string)R.ItemArray[0];
                    result.Add(strResult);
                }


                //while (dr.Read()) {
                //    string Name = (dr["ACNT_NAME"].ToString().Trim());
                //    result.Add(Name);
                //}

                return result;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does Firebug's Net panel or script debugger give you any clues?

Comment: After you host whether the function getting called successfully? because sometimes the absolute URL may change..

Comment: if i am not mistaken, you want to return some objects from server as JSON objects and use it on textbox? if you do, may be you forget to extend JSON size limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the URL: /../JQueryAutoComplete.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData. Rewrite it without resorting to "../".

Also to make sure you can get more information from the error function (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), its signature is
function(jQxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) [and not function(result)], use this instead as your error handler so that you check if it's failing because of a 404 or for some other reason:

```
function(xhr){
  alert(xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
}
```

xhr.status will print the http status code, for example 404, 500, etc
xhr.statusText will print the text associated with the code, for example Page not Found, Internal Server Error, etc

Comment: How can I rewrite that without the ../? The jQuery file is in the root of the app.

Comment: When you start with / the url is relative to the root of your site, so the /../ at the beginning of the url is a bit strange. If QueryAutoComplete.aspx is in the root of you site could you not just write the url as: /JQueryAutoComplete.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData?

Comment: I tried it and it worked OK in the local version but again nothing in the published one.

Comment: Did you try changing the error function so you could get more information? What http code was returned?

Comment: I Added the alert you mentioned and it now does nothing.

Comment: Forget that, I got it working and the error is 404 - not found

Comment: Now you know for sure that the URL is wrong. You have to rewrite the url you are using in your ajax call. Did you try:JQueryAutoComplete.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData? or /JQueryAutoComplete.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData?

Comment: Yes and they both don't work. The file accessing the jQuery (at the root) is two levels down from the root so I don't see how having none or only one / will get it back to the root to use the jQuery file.

Comment: Also, it won't hurt if you add contentType: 'application/json' to your ajax options, since your are making an ajax request with json

Comment: Can't you write the full url, as in:/something/somthing/JQueryAutoComplete.aspx instead of resorting to /../ (I'm pretty sure some web servers don't allow the ..)

Comment: I am using the .. to go up levels. I don't see how I could add the directories in there because I would end up back at two levels down.

Comment: If your url starts with "/" you start at the root of the website, it's only if you don't add the "/" at the beginning that your url is relative

Comment: You don't start at the root you start in the directory using relative paths. To get to the root you need to go up using ../ and then say for another folder within the root you would then do ../Folder so in my case to get back to the root I need /../

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150349/why-does-a-leading-slash-cause-relative-urls-in-links-on-my-site-to-resolve-to-t

Comment: I looked at it and oddly enough the last change I made to my code was just that; without the leading slash but it still gives me 404 not found :-S

Comment: I have tried examples of each using different leading / and without and and none of them work when published. I must of tried 10 different combinations or more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43342/discussion-between-rui-and-connersz)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the declaration in JQueryAutoComplete.aspx the property codefile needed to be changed to codebehind.

The codefile property prevent it accessing the .cs and that's where the 404 came from.